# How do I create a load balancer for a compute engine instance running Debian 9 and WordPress Multi-site as well as Lets Encrypt SSL integration?

Tags: wordpress, google-compute-engine, load-balancing, autoscaling

I have been researching about Load Balancing and auto-scaling on GCP, but I can't seem to get my setup correct.

I have an instance running Linux Debian 9 and Apache2 web server. I used the Bitnami setup and created a WordPress multisite.
So what I have done so far is, I have used a Google Cloud storage bucket for all my media files as to not fill up my instance drive. I have also separated my SQL database from the instance using Cloud SQL. So the files that are on the instance are the Wordpress installation files as well as the SSL files. I am using Let's Encrypt to generate my SSL certificates. I have a wildcard cert for my domain. And each site is then mapped to its own domain name using my static IP and Virtual Host configuration on Apache to direct the domain to the correct site.

As the site grows I know that I will need a load balancer of a sort. I have discovered that the best option for this kind of setup is to go with a Global Load Balancer. 
It would mainly be needed so that the server can handle all the requests.

Question:

Do I need internal or external load balancing?

In a managed instance group how do I get all instances to replicate with the Wordpress files and SSL files and setting etc? (not sure if I'm understanding this correctly)
I tried adding the Bitnami startup script which didn't help.

Comment: what about using a CDN to handle the SSL?

Comment: That could work, but the all the certs are generated automatically every 3 months on the server by certbot. How would that affect the choice to use a cdn? Im thinking it could still generate but then add some sort of script that uploads it on completion. What do you think?

Comment: if using Cloudflare for example, you can forget about the certs since it will do it for you

Comment: That could sort out the certs at least, I will look into that thanks.

Comment: You can remove the google-cloud-dns tag from this question, since Cloud DNS does not provide load balancing functionality. Google Cloud does LB at the L7 (HTTP/S) level only, see https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/.

Comment: I've recommend you to move this case to serverfault because this question is related with instances and architecture more than development.